# How to call an API from UI using private IP or localhost or 127.0.0.1 as API base URL, if UI and API both are deployed in a same VM in different port?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, iis, model-view-controller

I have two dot net applications. One is UI(.net framework), another is API (.net core 2.1).Now I deployed both application on an Azure VM (IIS) on different port. UI->80 port and API->3366 port. I am calling the API from my UI application using ajax call. When I am using the public IP of that VM as API base url, then it is working as expected. But when I am using private IP or localhost or 127.0.0.1 as base URL of API, then api call is not working.

My sample ajax call is below:

$.ajax({

```
   cache: false,

   type: 'get',

   async: true,

   contentType: 'application/json',   

   url: 'http://private-ip/api/user/getallusers',

   success: function (data) {

   }
```

})

**My expectation:**

As both applications are deployed on same VM, they should communicate with each other using private IP or localhost,insted of public IP of that VM . The agenda of using private ip or localhost is that I dont want to expose my API publicly.

Comment: It is impossible, as your JavaScript code runs in the web browsers on remote machines, not on the IIS machine.

Comment: You are correct Mr. Lex. I understood my mistake. Thanks for your comment.